# Do we ever use the pin capacitance of a digital circuit component (e.g ASIC, FPGA) in doing timing or data integrity analysis

Tags: capacitance, signal-integrity

As far as I understand, the pin capacitance on say an ASIC or FPGA effects the rise and fall time of the signal on it. It is also possible that the impedance offered by this capacitance to a very high speed signal creates an apparent mismatch with the PCB trace impedance and cause reflection. However, as of yet, I have not heard of the pin capacitance being used in any type of analysis.

I understand that the pin capacitance is not needed in timing analysis. When is it ever used?

Comment: does IBIS modelling and PCB signal analysis use these pin capacitance in their integrated models? Perhaps rolling them up into an equivalent parasitic capacitance for that particular net? Maybe pin capacitance is fairly standard, so it's just added on at each end as an assumption..

Comment: IBIS modeling does account for pin capacitance.

Comment: when do we need to use it and why?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the timing analysis of complex systems is divided into separate on-chip and off-chip domains in order to simplify the process of verification. Basically, a set of specifications is written that represent the "timing contract" at the pins of the chip(s) on the board. An internal verification is done to insure that each chip meets its specifications. A separate, external, PCB-level verification is done to insure that the timing relationships among the signals running between chips is also correct.

The pin capacitance is just one element that goes into the electrical modeling of the PCB traces for that external verification step.

Comment: I know about and understand Static Timing Analysis for FPGAs. In that we also include the delays between our FPGA and other external devices that communicate with our FPGA. Is that what you mean by internal verification? 

Thus, I am not familiar with this separate chip-to-chip that you refer to as external verification. Is there some book or resource that I can read to understand about this and how pin capacitance is used in it?